# inserting image into label

Tags: image, tkinter

I am told that I can add images to a label, but when I run the following code I get an error message:

unicode error: unicodeescape codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXX escape

My code is as simple as possible

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
x = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\user\Pictures\bee.gif")
w1 = Label(root, image=x).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

All the examples I've seen don't include the file path to the image but in that case Python can't find the image.

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 2):

Python is treating `\Users` as a unicode character because of the leading `\U`. Since it's an invalid unicode character, you get the error.

You can either use forward slashes (`"C:/Users/user/Pictures/bee.gif"`), a raw string (`r"C:\Users\user\Pictures\bee.gif"`), or escape the backslashes (`"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\bee.gif"`)